# Build fails with "Command CompileStoryboard failed with a nonzero exit code"

Tags: swift, xcode, storyboard

After archiving the problem i got this error and the app refused to build. Also, if i select a storyboard it crashed completely.

I have tried:

- Deleting Derived Data
- Restarting Xcode and Mac
- Cleaning build folder and then re-building again
- Adding SWIFT_ENABLE_BATCH_MODE in user settings
  I think I really tried everything I could and what I found on stack or google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing that finally helped me is using this command in terminal:

```
git stash
```

And project proceeded to build normally. After I used "git stash pop" the issue returned, so i just deleted the stash using:

```
git stash drop
```